# Variance of the Poisson Binomial Distribution

Tags: distributions, variance, poisson-binomial-distribution

Consider a sequence of $n$ independent Bernoulli trials drawn from a list of biases $p_1,p_2,...,p_n\in[0,1]$, respectively. We set the random variable $X$ to be the sum of these trials. On wikipedia, the distribution of $X$ is called the [Poisson binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_binomial_distribution). We define the sample mean and sample variance of our list of Bernoulli biases as 
$$
    \bar{p}=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^n p_i
$$ 
and 
$$
    \sigma_p^2
        =\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N(p_i-\bar{p})
        =\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N p_i^2 - \bar{p}^2.
$$

Since the trials are independent, it is easy to compute that 
$$
    \mathbb{E}[X]
        = \sum_{i=1}^n p_i = N\bar{p}
$$
and
\begin{align*}
    \mathbb{Var}[X]
        &= \sum_{i=1}^n p_i(1-p_i) \\
        &= N\bar{p} - N(\sigma_p^2+\bar{p}^2) \\
        &= N\bar{p}(1-\bar{p}) - N\sigma_p^2.
\end{align*}

The expectation value of $X$ is not surprising. Also, when $\sigma_p^2=0$ we must have $\bar{p}=p_1=\cdots=p_n$ and so $X$ is binomially distributed, which matches $\mathbb{Var}[X]$ computed above.

My confusion is this: why does the variance of $X$ go *down* as the sample variance $\sigma_p^2$ goes *up* (with $\bar{p}$ and $N$ fixed)? I find this very counter-intuitive, and would appreciate an explanation. I would expect with a greater variance of biases, there would be a broader distribution of possible sums of the result...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Think of the case where $n=2$.  If $p_1 = p_2 = 0.5$, this maximizes the variance of X.  If $p_1 = 0$ and $p_2 = 1$, then $X=1$ and there is no variance.

Comment: Interesting. So you are saying, I think, that: the closer a given $p$ is to either 0 or 1, the more you know about the outcome of that trial. If $\sigma_p^2$ goes up, other quantities being fixed, then some of the $p$ values will be closer to either 0 or 1 (and somehow the ones that moved closer to $p=1/2$ have less of an effect than those that moved away from it?). Therefore you should be more certain about the total of the trials.

Comment: That is precisely the idea.  You should be able to establish this by calculus, but since you had a formula that felt against your intuition I wanted to give you something simple.